# Network Error, react-native, nodejs, mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Dimensions, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import styled, {ThemeProvider} from "styled-components/native";
import {theme} from './theme';
import Input from './components/Input';
import Task from './components/Task';
import Axios from 'axios';

const Container = styled.SafeAreaView`
flex: 1;
background-color: ${({theme}) => theme.background};
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;`;

const Title = styled.Text`
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 600;
color: ${({theme}) => theme.main};
align-self: flex-start;
margin: 0px 20px`;

const List = styled.ScrollView`
    flex: 1;
    width: ${({width})=> width - 40}px;`;

export default function App() {
    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

    const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    const getTasks = () => {
        Axios.get('/todos')
          .then(res => {
            setTasks(res.data);
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      };

    const _addTask = () => {
        const newTaskObject = {
            text: newTask,        
            completed: false 
        };
        Axios.post('/create', newTaskObject)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
          setNewTask('');
          getTasks();
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    };

    const _deleteTask = id => {
        const currentTasks = Object.assign({},tasks);
        delete currentTasks[id];
        setTasks(currentTasks);
    };

    const _toggleTask = id => {
        const currentTasks = Object.assign({}, tasks);
        currentTasks[id]['completed'] = !currentTasks[id]['completed'];
        setTasks(currentTasks);
    };

    const _updateTask = item => {
        const currentTasks = Object.assign({}, tasks);
        currentTasks[item.id] = item;
        setTasks(currentTasks);
    };

    const _handleTextChange = text => {
        setNewTask(text);
    };

    const _onBlur = () => {
        setNewTask('');
    };
    

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Container>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"
                backgroundColor={theme.background}/>
                <Title>TODO List</Title>
                <Input placeholder="+ Add a Task"
                value={newTask}
                onChangeText={_handleTextChange}
                onSubmitEditing={_addTask}
                onBlur={_onBlur}/>
                <List width={width}>
                    {Object.values(tasks)
                    .reverse()
                    .map(item => (
                        <Task key={item.id} item={item} deleteTask={_deleteTask} toggleTask={_toggleTask} updateTask={_updateTask}/>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'thtjdgk0901!',
  database : 'todolistSystem',
});

app.post("/create", (req, res) => {
  const { text, completed } = req.body;
  
  db.query(
    "INSERT INTO TODOLISTSYSTEM.TODOS (TEXT, COMPLETED) VALUES (?,?)",
    [text, completed],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send("Inserted values successfully!");
      }
    }
  );
});

app.get("/todos", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM TODOLISTSYSTEM.TODOS", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(`Selected values successfully!`);
    }
  });
});

app.put("/todos", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  const text = req.body.text;
  const completed = req.body.completed;


  db.query(
    "UPDATE TODOLISTSYSTEM.TODOS SET TEXT = ?, COMPLETED = ? WHERE ID = ?;",
    [text, completed, id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(`Updated values successfully!`);
      }
    }
  );
});

app.delete("/todos/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  console.log(id);
  db.query(
    "DELETE FROM TODOLISTSYSTEM.TODOS WHERE ID = ?",
    [id],
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(`Deleted values successfully!`);
      }
    }
  );
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

I checked the connection with nodejs and mysql through Talend api tester and all worked properly.
But when i try to add task, i can see this message.
LOG  [Error: Network Error]
I think there is a problem on the react native side. But I can't solve it. Please help me connect
[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx6Kl.png)

I want to connect the database and the app.